# Magento: adding duties/taxes to a quote during review

Tags: php, magento

I need to make a call to a 3rd party API to get up to date Duties/Taxes for international shipping during the review stage of the checkout process. I have the API call ready to go, however I am missing a way to add the returned duties and taxes to the quote.

Is there a built in way to do this?

im hoping there is something like

```
$quote->addCostComponent("Duties", 5.0);
```

Comment: yes, there is. but i forgot how exactly. wouldnt this better be asked at the magento forums?

Comment: @Joe, the Magento forums are a wasteland if you're looking for help with code. Since this is a code-related question, it seems more than appropriate for the audience here.

Comment: @JosephMastey Regarding magento and so, do look at [area 51 magento proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48872/magento)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to perform such steps:

1. First of all you need to create attributes for your custom duties/taxes for displaying them in order, not only just add to the grand total. There should be at least two attributes one for value in website currency (used in payment capture and it should have `base_` prefix) and one value in displayed currency (used just for displaying amount in desired currency for customer). This attributes should be added to every entity with financial part (quote_address, order, invoice). For instance it should be: `base_your_attribute_code` and `your_attribute_code` with decimal type.
2. Then you need create your total collector model that should be extended from Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract and implement collect and fetch methods like in this example:

   ```
   /**
    * Your custom total model
    *
    */
   class Your_Module_Model_Total_Custom extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
   {
       /** 
        * Constructor that should initiaze 
        */
       public function __construct()
       {
           $this->setCode('your_attribute_code');
       }

       /**
        * Used each time when collectTotals is invoked
        * 
        * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address
        * @return Your_Module_Model_Total_Custom
        */
       public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
       {
           parent::collect($address);

           // ... Some your api calls to retrive amount ...

           // Set base amount of your custom fee
           $this->_setBaseAmount($calculatedAmount);

           // Set amount of your custom fee in displayed currency
           $this->_setAmount(
               $address->getQuote()->getStore()->convertPrice($calculatedAmount, false)
           );

           return $this;
       }

       /**
        * Used each time when totals are displayed
        * 
        * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address
        * @return Your_Module_Model_Total_Custom
        */
       public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
       {
           // Display total only if it is not zero
           if ($address->getYourAttributeCode() != 0) {
               $address->addTotal(array(
                   'code' => $this->getCode(),
                   'title' => 'My Custom Duty',
                   'value' => $address->getYourAttributeCode()
               ));
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. After you the collector model is created you need add it to configuration:

   ```
   <config>
       <global>
           <sales>
               <quote>
                   <totals>
                       <your_total_code>
                           <class>your_module/total_custom</class>
                           <before>grand_total</before>
                           <after>shipping</after>
                       </your_total_code>
                   </totals>
               </quote>
           </sales>
       </global>
   </config>
   ```

   - **class** node contains the class alias of your collector model
   - **before** and **after** nodes indicate invocation order of your collector.
4. You need to add your total attributes to field-sets that will be used for copying calculated data into order or invoice:

   ```
   <config>
       <global>
           <fieldsets>
               <!-- copies data from quote address to order during the order placement -->
               <sales_convert_quote_address>
                   <base_your_attribute_code><to_order>*</to_order></base_your_attribute_code>
                   <your_attribute_code><to_order>*</to_order></your_attribute_code>
               </sales_convert_quote_address>

               <!-- copies data from order to invoice/shipment/creditmemo during their creation -->
               <sales_convert_order>
                   <base_your_attribute_code><to_invoice>*</to_invoice><to_shipment>*</to_shipment><to_cm>*</to_cm></base_your_attribute_code>
                   <your_attribute_code><to_invoice>*</to_invoice><to_shipment>*</to_shipment><to_cm>*</to_cm></your_attribute_code>
               </sales_convert_order>

           </fieldsets>
       </global>
   </config>
   ```
5. After performing this steps you will be able to see your custom fee in order totals

Comment: I'm still looking at what might have gone wrong but the calculated tax amount is showing in the total, but it's not appearing as it's own line item

Comment: @rennat, have you defined `fetch` method?

Comment: yes, I added some debug logging and I'm wondering if it has to do with the naming conventions for the getYourAttributeCode() method? I have used BJLTAX in every instance, but getBJLTAX() returns nothing, in fact so does getBjltax() and getbjltax().

Comment: @rennat try `getData('BJLTAX')`. Yes you are right, `getBJLTAX` will not be the same as `getData` ones, because Magento uses each capital letter in method name as start of the next word, so your method will be transformed into `getData('B_J_L_T_A_X')`

Comment: so what should i look out for when getData('BJLTAX') returns nothing

Comment: I think that my attributes might not have been created. I'm using a setup script but I think it might not have been called, how do I call a setup script manually?

Comment: @rennat have you added it via configuration?

Comment: yes i've set it up like here http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/installing_custom_attributes_with_your_module

Comment: @rennat is your module setup class extended from Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup ? If not, please change it, then remove record from `core_resource` table with the name of your module setup  resource.

Comment: My setup class is extending `Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup` although the class is empty, originally I had defined `getDefaultEntities` then you directed me to use `addAttribute` instead so there is nothing in the setup class.

Comment: @rennat, ok, maybe you can place all your module files somewhere?