# How to set Dynamic Discount on each Cart Item programmatically?

Tags: php, magento, checkout, discount

I want to set the Discount (say $10) per Item dynamically, after a custom button is pressed, in the Checkout Cart page. I have checked some of the coding of Magento, to find that:

- Mainly the "`Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address`" class is affected always, when anybody (any Magento code) is talking about discount.
- There are 2 instances of "`Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address`" - one for "**billing**" address type & the other for "**shipping**" address type, but the latter one is mainly used for coupon code related discounts.

After checking these area, I went on to write some code, targeting the "**shipping**" address type of "`Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address`", as:-

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$objShippingAddress = $cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
$discountAmount = 10;

$objShippingAddress->setDiscountDescription('any description');
$objShippingAddress->addTotal(array(
    'code' => 'discount',
    'title' => "Custom Discount",
    'value' => -$discountAmount,
));

$totalDiscountAmount = $discountAmount;
$subtotalWithDiscount = $discountAmount;
$baseTotalDiscountAmount = $discountAmount;
$baseSubtotalWithDiscount = $discountAmount;

$objShippingAddress->setDiscountAmount($totalDiscountAmount);
$objShippingAddress->setSubtotalWithDiscount($subtotalWithDiscount);
$objShippingAddress->setBaseDiscountAmount($baseTotalDiscountAmount);
$objShippingAddress->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount($baseSubtotalWithDiscount);

$objShippingAddress->setGrandTotal($objShippingAddress->getGrandTotal() - $objShippingAddress->getDiscountAmount());
$objShippingAddress->setBaseGrandTotal($objShippingAddress->getBaseGrandTotal() - $objShippingAddress->getBaseDiscountAmount());
```

But still I don't get any line in the "`totals`" section of my checkout cart page & in the order review section of checkout one-page.

Comment: Is there no one who can try this one? It's tough I admit, but please there must be somebody who have tried this in his Magento's stint...

Comment: check Ivan's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877413/magento-adding-duties-taxes-to-a-quote-during-review/4879662#4879662 it worked for me.

Comment: @OSdave is right. It is the best way to add custom fee or discount.

Comment: @KnowledgeCraving can you shed some light on where/when is this code snippet called?

Answer (score 0):

We had a request to setup discount tiers. Since we could not do them using the current discount model, we  made modifications to the couponPostAction in the CartController. We setup a dummy coupon and was able to, based on other information about the customer, offer a tiered discount scheme with that coupon.