# Magento upfront payment

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

For a future project we have been assigned to create a simple concept (inside Magento) that would has to do the following:

**A customer has the ability to choose between different shipping methods, one of them being "Ship2Shop", which sends the product to a physical store of choice and the customer has to go an pick it up.
When a customer selects this "ship2shop" shipping method, a certain percentage (eg: 25%) of the total amount has to be paid online (via a pre-defined payment method) and the remaining 75% has to be paid in the physical store when the customer goes and pick up the products he ordered.**

How would you go about this?

Idea that we were having is modify the checkout/order session and modify the "grand total" amount (saving the original in a session ofcourse). When the customer is then sent to the external payment processor the "modified grand total" is sent along. Once the customer returns on the magento platform we would modify the order by restoring the original grand total the way it was and updating the total paid and total due amount.

Anyone got any other ideas about this?

**EDIT:**
After feedback from Anton S below I managed to add an "advance payment total". However Im still having a problem
In the config.xml I have added the following in the  tag:

acsystems_advancepayment/total_custom
                    grand_total

I want my advance payment to show AFTER the grand total, for some reason, magento won't do that...

**EDIT2:** Collect method

```
public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        parent::collect($address);

        $quote = $address->getQuote();
        $advancePaymentAmount = 0;
        $baseAdvancePaymentAmount = 0;

        $items = $address->getAllItems();
        if (!count($items)) {
            $address->setAdvancePaymentAmount($advancePaymentAmount);
            $address->setBaseAdvancePaymentAmount($baseAdvancePaymentAmount);
            return $this;
        }

        $address->setBaseAdvancePayment($address->getGrandTotal()*(0.25));
        $address->setAdvancePayment($address->getGrandTotal()*(0.25));
        $address->setAdvancePaymentAmount($address->getGrandTotal()*(0.25));
        $address->setBaseAdvancePaymentAmount($address->getGrandTotal()*(0.25));
        $address->setGrandTotal($address->getGrandTotal() - $address->getAdvancePaymentAmount());
        $address->setBaseGrandTotal($address->getBaseGrandTotal()-$address->getBaseAdvancePaymentAmount());

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: so what does this do $address->setAdvancePayment($calculatedAmount); ?

Comment: If I don't set it, then my "advance payment" row doesn't show up in the cart overview/review on checkout. (I guess it's the same as ->setData("advance_payment")

Comment: ok your issue is that baseAmount and amount won't get cleared during your collection if it is called multiple times in a row and thats what paretn::collect($address); is doing at the top of your method. However you must ensure that your calculatedAmount always starts the calculation from 0

Comment: I have updated the collect method, it seems to be working now so thanks alot! ;) You see any strange things in the method that you do not agree on or that might give problems later on? (Thanks again for all the help)

Comment: i'll edit this in my answer, don't mess with other totals in your object as they don't know about your object

Comment: @AntonS: The bit of code that updates the grand total is taken from Discount.php (app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Discount.php) where the grand total is also updated. Ill see if I can find a solution by making the "advance payment" negative.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3616/discussion-between-kenny-and-anton-s)

Comment: I edited my answer. Note that you don't have to set your own variables as the api has defined some for you already (in parent context) and you don't have to update grand totals and subtotals as they are collected over all totals in total object collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refer to this thread where adding total objects is explained [Magento: adding duties/taxes to a quote during review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877413/magento-adding-duties-taxes-to-a-quote-during-review)

Basically you should add your own total object based on your shipping method selection, then it will also be shown in totals as separate row and you can show this in every e-mail or place where totals are exposed

```
public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{

    //this is for the loop that you are in when totals are collected 
    parent::collect($address);

    $quote = $address->getQuote();

    //variables for your own object context
    $advancePaymentAmount = 0;
    $baseAdvancePaymentAmount = 0;

    $items = $address->getAllItems();
    if (!count($items)) {
        $address->setAdvancePaymentAmount($advancePaymentAmount);
        $address->setBaseAdvancePaymentAmount($baseAdvancePaymentAmount);
        return $this;
    }

    //calculated based on other total object and don't edit other totals inside your own as your calculations would be always false and so would be next total object in the cycle and so on
    $baseAdvancePaymentAmount = $address->getBaseGrandTotal()*(0.25);
    $advancePaymentAmount = $address->getQuote()->getStore()->convertPrice($baseAdvancePaymentAmount, false);

    //this is just for your own object context
    $address->setBaseAdvancePaymentAmount($baseAdvancePaymentAmount);
    $address->setAdvancePaymentAmount($advancePaymentAmount);

    /* 
     * this is for the loop that you are in when totals are collected and 
     * those are set to 0 for each totals collecting cycle 
     */

    $this->_setBaseAmount($baseAdvancePaymentAmount);
    $this->_setAmount($advancePaymentAmount);

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at it and mark as answer if this really is the solution we are looking for, thanks in advance!

Comment: I successfully added an "advance payment" total to quote_address, orders and invoices. There are still a few things that are bothering me, I will be sending you a message ;) [Edit: can't seem to message you :D] See question post for more info.

Comment: Each total object has order that you can apply to it in your system.xml and Grand Total is somewhat hardcoded to be the last in the row, see grand total block for this condition

Comment: Another issue I'm having: the collect seems to add the custom amount twice everytime... Example if I set $calculatedAmount to 10, it will always show up as 20...

Comment: you have to reveal your collect method code, please do so  in your question

Answer (score -2):

Another option is to change the "grand_total" in your payment module, that way the sessions aren't altered..

Comment: We also thought about this, but when a customer is referred to the external payment processor (with grand total $100 for example) and he returns to the Magento platform after payment, it will verify whether the paid amount equals the grand total that was saved in the customers session (in order).

Comment: this is nasty, if you need to implement that then implement your own total object as altering other totals will ruin the calculation pretty fast