# How do I get quote totals before saving payment method?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I am trying to create a one step checkout, but in the checkout page I have problem with order review part . When I select a payment method for example "cash on deliver" has 5$ extra, or "checkorder" has %4 discount or "credit card payment" adds extra to the order total. 
I need a way to calculate the discounts before saving the payment method. Any suggestion?

Comment: duplicate covering the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877413/magento-adding-duties-taxes-to-a-quote-during-review

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because we are talking about Magento, there are several ways you could do this. The best way to implement that functionality would be to create your own total models for the discounts or additional charges.

### How to create custom Magento total models

To create your own total model you first need to create a module, and add the total models to the configuration.

```
<global>
  <sales>
    <quote>
      <totals>
        <your_total>
          <class>your_module/quote_address_total_yourTotal</class>
          <after>shipping</after><!-- calculate after these total models -->
          <before>grand_total,tax</before><!-- calculate before these total models -->
        </your_total>
      </totals>
    </quote>
    <order_invoice>
      <totals>
        <your_total>
          <class>your_module/order_invoice_total_yourTotal</class>
          <after>shipping</after>
          <before>grand_total,tax</before>
        </your_total>
      </totals>
    </order_invoice>
    <order_creditmemo>
      <totals>
        <your_total>
          <class>your_module/order_creditmemo_total_yourTotal</class>
          <after>shipping</after>
          <before>grand_total,tax</before>
        </your_total>
      </totals>
    </order_creditmemo>
  </sales>
  <pdf>
    <totals>
      <your_total translate="title">
        <title>Your Total</title>
        <source_field>your_total</source_field>
        <font_size>7</font_size>
        <display_zero>0</display_zero>
        <sort_order>450</sort_order>
      </your_total>
    </totals>
  </pdf>
</global>
```

Then implement the three classes specified in the XML.
The quote address total needs to extend `sales/quote_address_total_abstract` and implement the two methods `collect()` and `fetch()`.

```
class Your_Module_Model_Quote_Address_Total_YourTotal
    extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
{
    // Calculate your total value
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        parent::collect($address);

        // Calculate the totals based on the information in the $address
        // and the $address->getQuote()
        // To get the items in the cart use $address->getAllItems()
        // To get the payment method use getPayment()->getMethodInstance()
        // etc

        // When your totals are known..
        $this->_addAmount($total); // store view currency amount
        $this->_addBaseAmount($baseTotal); // base currency amount

        // Also store in address for later reference in fetch()
        $address->setMyTotal($total);
        $address->setBaseMyTotal($baseTotal);

        return $this;
    }

    // If the total should be displayed in the cart and the checkout
    // add them to the address model here, otherwise just return
    // (it will still be calculated and added to the grand total)
    public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        if ($address->getMyTotal() > 0)
        {
            $address->addTotal(array(
                'code'  => $this->getCode(),
                'title' => Mage::helper('your_module')->__('Your Total'),
                'value' => $address->getMyTotal()
            ));
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

The next class specified in the config XML is the invoice total model `your_module/order_invoice_total_yourTotal`.

```
class Your_Module_Model_Order_Invoice_Total_YourTotal
    extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice_Total_Abstract
{
    // Collect the totals for the invoice
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice $invoice)
    {
        $order = $invoice->getOrder();
        $myTotal = $order->getMyTotal();
        $baseMyTotal = $order->getBaseMyTotal();

        $invoice->setGrandTotal($invoice->getGrandTotal() + $myTotal);
        $invoice->setBaseGrandTotal($invoice->getBaseGrandTotal() + $basemyTotal);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The final class you need to implement in the creditmemo total model, which is just like the invoice total model, only it extends the abstract class `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Creditmemo_Total_Abstract`.

You will also need to add the attributes using a setup script:

```
/**
 * @var Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup $installer
 */
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/setup', 'default_setup');

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('order', 'base_your_total', array(
    'label' => 'Base Your Total',
    'type'  => 'decimal',
));

$installer->addAttribute('order', 'your_total', array(
    'label' => 'Your Total',
    'type'  => 'decimal',
));

$installer->addAttribute('invoice', 'base_your_total', array(
    'label' => 'Base Your Total',
    'type'  => 'decimal',
));

$installer->addAttribute('invoice', 'your_total', array(
    'label' => 'Your Total',
    'type'  => 'decimal',
));

$installer->addAttribute('creditmemo', 'base_your_total', array(
    'label' => 'Base Your Total',
    'type'  => 'decimal',
));

$installer->addAttribute('creditmemo', 'your_total', array(
    'label' => 'Your Total',
    'type'  => 'decimal',
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

In order to display the new total in the admin area, you need to add a totals block for it using layout XML. Register a layout update file for the `adminhtml` area in your module. Here is a sample content:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">

  <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="order_totals">
      <block type="your_module/sales_total_yourTotal" name="total_your_total" as="your_total"/>
    </reference>
  </adminhtml_sales_order_view>

  <adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_new>
    <reference name="invoice_totals">
      <block type="your_module/sales_total_yourTotal" name="total_your_total" as="your_total"/>
    </reference>
  </adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_new>

  <adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_updateqty>
    <reference name="invoice_totals">
      <block type="your_module/sales_total_yourTotal" name="total_your_total" as="your_total"/>
    </reference>
  </adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_updateqty>

  <adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_view>
    <reference name="invoice_totals">
      <block type="your_module/sales_total_yourTotal" name="total_your_total" as="your_total"/>
    </reference>
  </adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_view>

  <adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_new>
    <reference name="creditmemo_totals">
      <block type="your_module/sales_total_yourTotal" name="total_your_total" as="your_total"/>
    </reference>
  </adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_new>

  <adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_view>
    <reference name="creditmemo_totals">
      <block type="your_module/sales_total_yourTotal" name="total_your_total" as="your_total"/>
    </reference>
  </adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_view>

</layout>
```

If you don't want to display your total somewhere, just leave it out. It will still be calculated.
Okay, almost there. Finally, the admin area total block class implementation:

```
// Many ways to implement this, here is one option
class Your_Module_Block_Sales_Total_YourTotal
    extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{
    public function initTotals()
    {
        $parent = $this->getParentBlock();

        $value = $parent->getSource()->getMyTotal();

        if ($value > 0)
        {
            $total = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code'  => 'my_total',
            'value' => $parent->getSource()->getMyTotal(),
            'base_value' => $parent->getSource()->getBaseMyTotal(),
            'label' => $this->__('My Total'),
            'field' => 'my_total'
            ));
            $parent->addTotal($total, 'my_total');
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Now the only thing missing is the fieldset to copy the total amount from the quote address to the order, and from the order to the invoice and creditmemo. Add the following XML to the config.xml:

```
<fieldsets>
    <sales_convert_quote_address>
        <shipping_surcharge><to_order>*</to_order></shipping_surcharge>
        <base_shipping_surcharge><to_order>*</to_order></base_shipping_surcharge>
    </sales_convert_quote_address>
    <sales_convert_order>
        <shipping_surcharge><to_invoice>*</to_invoice><to_cm>*</to_cm></shipping_surcharge>
    </sales_convert_order>
</fieldsets>
```

And thats it. The total will be displayed everywhere (including the generated PDF's).
As I said, there are many other ways to simply update the values of the total models already present in the core, but this is the full blown way to implement it.

Comment: Nice answer. Do you have a clue what to do if there is a tax involved. See also my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194281/sort-algorithm-magento-totals-sorted-wrongly

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your time, but I have tried the almost same thing, the problem with your solition is to get the totals I need to save the quote. But I need to get the totals before saving the quote. Let's say I have three different payment methods and every method has different rules. I want to show the totals right next to payment methods name, when they are shown to the user for selecting one. So I need to calculate the totals before it was selected and quote object was saved. I hope I made my question a little bit clearer.

Comment: I done all the steps as described above. It worked. I wants to enable this only for particular shipping method, what must be the changes?

Comment: Kuku, Just check for the shipment method in your total models `collect()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The order has `setShippingAmount` and `getShippingAmount` methods. Modify to add for 'cash on deliver'.

Create a method and add it as an observer to `checkout_type_onepage_save_order` event in `/etc/config.xml`

```
# file: /Model/Observer.php
<?php
    class Handling_Fee_Model_Observer 
    {
       public function updateHandling ($observer)
       {
          $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
          $shipping_amount = $order->getShippingAmount();
          $order->setShippingAmount($shipping_amount * (1 + 0,5));
          return $this;
       }
    }
```

This is a part of your question. In my opinion, you can customize left parts in this way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I need to do this calculation before the order will be saved. All the shipping method selection, payment method selection and the order review will be on the same page shown all together. I wonder if I can get the discount calculation after a payment method was selected programmaticly.
not:pardon mesajı yazdıktan sonra gördüm sizde Türkmüşsünüz..

Comment: Orhan, just try another observer method instead of onepage_save_order. To get full list of events available in magento [Magento Event List](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) NOT : Bende o kadar sorunun içinden seni seçtim zaten :)